# Magento category tree

Tags: php, magento, categories, product

I am having this situation.
    I got all my categories imported in Magento, now I want to import my products.

Now the ID's don't match and I was thinking to lookup a category in magento by the categorypath (Default Category/Products/...) and get the 'actual' ID from that category so I can 'map' the right categoryIds to the to-be-imported-category.

How can I load a category by its path instead of its id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could load the category collection and filter by the path :

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
                                                ->addAttributeToFilter('path','your/path');

$count = $categories->count();
```

Then, if your collection contains one element :

```
$categoryId = $categories->getFirstItem()->getId();
```

So you get your category ID.